# Icons missing in 16.10

Tags: icons, 16.10

Desktop, taskbar, and search icons are missing on a freshly installed Ubuntu 16.10. possibly after switching to the high contrast theme. Reverting the theme or rebooting does not repair the missing icons. About half of the icons are missing and include standard Ubuntu icons, e.g., settings. How do I restore the icons?